# How to refactor function which concatenates dataframes multiple times?

Tags: python, pandas

I found my bottleneck in my python script. This function takes for my csv over 4 min.

Is it better to use dataframe assign function with lambda here? And is this possible for my function I wrote?

This function checks if an article nr is more than once in the dataframe and when this is true, it should mark all these rows as an variant.

```py
def mark_variants(df):
    single_prods = df["ArtikelNr"].unique()
    varianten = pd.DataFrame()
    non_varianten = pd.DataFrame()
    for prod in single_prods:
        filtered_prods = df[df.ArtikelNr == prod]
        if len(filtered_prods["ArtikelNr"]) > 1:
            varianten = pd.concat([varianten, filtered_prods])
        else:
            non_varianten = pd.concat([non_varianten, filtered_prods])
    varianten["variante"] = 1
    non_varianten["variante"] = 0
    return pd.concat([varianten, non_varianten])
```

Comment: Also worth mentioning: any time you get the unique list of values, and filter by each value, you are adding multiple passes over the dataframe. It is usually faster to use `groupby('ArtikelNr')` to separate a dataframe into multiple dataframes, because it can do that in one pass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are concatenating dataframes multiple times within the for-loop, which is computationally expensive.

You did not provide a reproducible example, so I can not test it for myself, but:

- using lists instead of empty dataframes to instantiate `varianten` and `non_varianten`
- and concatenating only once the for-loop is over

might speed up things.

Here is how you could refactor your function and give it a try:

```py
def mark_variants(df):
    single_prods = df["ArtikelNr"].unique()
    varianten = []
    non_varianten = []

    for prod in single_prods:
        filtered_prods = df[df.ArtikelNr == prod]
        if len(filtered_prods["ArtikelNr"]) > 1:
            varianten.append(filtered_prods)
        else:
            non_varianten.append(filtered_prods)

    varianten = pd.concat(varianten)
    non_varianten = pd.concat(non_varianten)
    varianten["variante"] = 1
    non_varianten["variante"] = 0
    return pd.concat([varianten, non_varianten])
```